# Launch other apps with Xamarin

Tags: facebook, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I'm trying to create an app that has buttons to open other apps on an android device. Apps such as Facebook, Twitter and Instagram. How do I open another app on an android device by using xamarin?

Comment: Hey and welcome to Stack. Please have a look how a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is "asked", please update your own question to fit in :)

Comment: String uri = "facebook://facebook.com/inbox";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this with the app's package name.

```
Intent i = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.appname");
StartActivity(i);
```

For facebook it is

```
Intent i = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
StartActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It work perfectly. Is it possible to display the Facebook App in the Xamarin form. For example, like a webview?

Comment: No worries. You should consider using webview about that. U cant display the app but u can display the facebook internet page. And if this worked for you u can set the answer as accepted answer.

Comment: How can I click elements (`buttons`, `textboxes`, etc) on the `intent` that was created?